# Difficulty outputting an array of indexes from an existing array consisting of strings

Tags: function, javascript

So I am trying to create a function that searches through an array based on a searchTerm. If the elements within the array have the searchTerm in it, it should output **ALL** of indexes inside of MyArray[];.

I hope I have explained clearly, thanks in advance.

Comment: Since I see you're pretty new here, do you realize that the proper etiquette on StackOverflow is that when/if an answer answers your question, you should mark it as "the answer" by clicking on the checkmark in the upper left of the selected answer?  That's what helps make SO a better resource and it's part of the incentive process for people to provide answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a corrected version:

```
var colours = ["I like the colour red", "I hate the colour yellow", "I love the colour blue"];

function myFunction(colours, searchTerm) {
    var myArray = [];
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
       if (colours[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {
           myArray.push(i);
        }
    }
    return myArray;
}

alert(myFunction(colours,"colour")) //Should return indexes 0,1,2 in myArray
```

And a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GDM9R/.

I had to fix a lot of issues:

1. You weren't adding results to myArray properly.
2. You weren't adding the index to myArray.
3. You weren't testing the results of `.indexOf()` properly (it returns -1 when no match).
4. You were iterating over the length of the search phrase, not the number of items in the array.
5. You didn't declare `i` as a local variable so it was an implicit global variable.

Comment: `.push()` is how you add items to the end of an array.  Why would you want to avoid that?  See [here for doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: Sorry, i was just curious to see whether there was another way to do it. Thank you for telling me where I went wrong. Now I can actually learn from the mistakes I made. Thank you

Comment: There are other ways to add to the end of an array, but `.push()` is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

`myArray = colours[i]` does not append to the array.

```
myArray.push(a);
```